# "This file may harm your pc" warning when downloading

Tags: java, google-chrome, safari

Hello so i made a program in java that i want other people to download. But everytime someone downloads he sees a message with a warning prompt saying the file could harm his computer. He then gets the option to dismiss it or he can choose to download it anyways. How do you avoid this message?

Comment: If it's a jar, it's a default message from chrome.

Comment: How to avoid this problem: don’t give download links to executables; or use a different browser.

Comment: You can't avoid the truth.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior for most browsers. It exists to protect users who get tricked into downloading and running "software." Usually it's a file with a naming scheme like `totallylegitfile.pdf.exe`. Normal Windows users don't change the default to hide known extensions, so it just looks like a pdf file.

Just let your users know that this might happen and tell them that it is safe.